# java - Storing unique items in a collection

Tags: java, collections

I have a loop running through a collection of items and store only unique items in a new collection. 
For the new collection of unique items, I primarily choose `LinkedHashSet` data structure. But another way is having an `ArrayList` and calling contains method to check if that `ArrayList` already contain that item or not.
Which one is faster with less overhead?

Comment: LinkedHashSet is designed to do what you need. Why would you want to have the overhead of checking for duplicates and use ArrayList? Do you have certain benefit you might expect from using ArrayList?

Comment: @clinomaniac, thank you for your answer,I was just curious to know which one has less overhead

Comment: You don't even have to explicitly loop if you're using a hash set. Just pass your collection into the constructor.

Comment: Checking contains on a `Set` is `O(1)`, checking `contains` on a `List ` is `O(n)`. Therefore adding `n` items to a `Set` is `O(n)`, whereas addings `n` items to a `List` whilst guaranteeing uniqueness is `O(n^2)`. Answer your question?

Comment: yes, your answer is quite clear and convincing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `LinkedHashSet`. It is made for what you need. Searching entire `ArrayList` every time you need to insert something will be very slow performing `(O(n) every time))`. You can use the contains method but it will still be much slower than inserting into the `LinkedHashSet` because that is `O(n)` in the background. To be very accurate about performance, you would need to go over your sizes and operations. As in if you need to insert a few times and then read a lot of times then `ArrayList` might turn out to be better. But if you are inserting a lot and reading less times then `LinkedHashSet` will be much faster.